# How to locate elements on a webpage which appear after a button click in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a new Python programmer. Lately, I started working on automation/scraping. Currently, I am stuck in a situation where a page appears after a button click, and I am not able to locate elements on that page.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"/Users/prateep/Downloads/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://example.com")

driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(10)

button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-IRR-buttons")

button.click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element("P52_NAME").send_keys("Test!!!")

selectStatus = Select(driver.find_element("P52_ASSESSMENT_STATUS_ID"))

selectStatus.select_by_value("O - Open")

driver.close()
```

**Output:-**

```
driver.find_element_by_name("P52_NAME").send_keys("Test!!!")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prateep/Aegis_Automation/Aegis_Automation.py", line 25, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_name("P52_NAME").send_keys("Test!!!")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 658, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1238, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="P52_NAME"]"}
```

Comment: Update the question with the HTML of the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is at this line

```
driver.find_element("P52_NAME").send_keys("Test!!!")
```

You are using `find_element` wrong.

Let's see what do we have in `find_element` internally

```
def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
    """
    Find an element given a By strategy and locator. Prefer the find_element_by_* methods when
    possible.

    :Usage:
        element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')

    :rtype: WebElement
    """
    if self.w3c:
        if by == By.ID:
            by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
            value = '[id="%s"]' % value
        elif by == By.TAG_NAME:
            by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
        elif by == By.CLASS_NAME:
            by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
            value = ".%s" % value
        elif by == By.NAME:
            by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
            value = '[name="%s"]' % value
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
        'using': by,
        'value': value})['value']
```

As you can see, we have to use it with

1. `By.ID`
2. `By.CLASS_NAME`
3. `By.TAG_NAME`
4. `By.LINK_TEXT`
5. `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`
6. `By.NAME`
7. `By.CSS_SELECTOR`
8. `By.XPATH`

If `P52_NAME` is the name and if it is unique and represent the desired element in `HTMLDOM`, then ideally you should use

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "P52_NAME").send_keys("Test!!!")
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `NAME` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Update:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "iframe xpath")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, ""))).send_keys("")
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey, Thanks for the detailed response. I changed the code as per your  recommendation, but strangely I am getting the same error.  I changed to driver.find_element(By.NAME, "P52_NAME").send_keys("Test!!!").  Getting error:- selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="P52_NAME"]"}.    Also, the page which contains these elements is not initially present, it opens only when I click a button.

Comment: Is it opening in new tab or new windows ? or in same windows/tab ?

Comment: Also, Please share HTML for `P52_NAME`

Comment: It is opening in the same page within an "iframe" after a button click.

Comment: You will have to switch to iframe first, and then you can use the this ID P52_NAME_LABEL

Comment: Please see above how to switch to iframe and then how to send keys. You will have to find iframe XPath as well. Steps are written above.

Comment: <iframe src="/pls/apex/gis/r/aegis/52?clear=RP,52&amp;session=17294682429612&amp;cs=3eQ8izTBsw6IHIezFqoe8YVNhOouKPLeobU1b615ylv5jrTre87rfZ-C2qk2XXHWeokZw-Q9Q3Rl1I0keMHusGw&amp;dialogCs=35bEQ2Zlj2AnR5RA8pUWY3uo1jA8oCIBAb48UlLoUNlV7rhXnVF4xkabEQAfferHIC7GncZ_o1oKMvqFO5hRUQ" title="Activity" width="100%" height="100%" style="min-width: 95%;height:100%;" scrolling="auto">  </iframe>

Comment: I am using driver.switch_to.frame("Activity") for the above iframe, is it correct or I am missing something. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: //iframe[@title='Activity'], please use this xpath. Also I have updated the answer above, you just need to replace the xpath above.